# Creating a guess a number game

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and am trying to write a guess the number game. I can't get the counter to stop at zero and display the answer if the user does not guess the right number in three guesses. Any suggestions on how to correct the code?

```
num=16
guess=0
guess_limit=3
max_guesses=0

while max_guesses<guess_limit:
    guess=int(input("Enter a number between 1-99:"))
    if guess==num:
        print("you guessed the number correctly you have {} guesses remaining".format(max_guesses+3))
        max_guesses-=1
        break
    elif guess>=num:
        print("You guessed to high you have {} guesses remaining".format(max_guesses+2))
        max_guesses-=1
    elif guess<=num:
        print("you guessed to low you have {} guesses remmaining".format(max_guesses+2))
        max_guesses-=1
    elif max_guesses==guess_limit:
        print("Sorry you have run out of guesses  you have {} guesses 
remaining".format(max_guesses+1))
        print("the number was",num)
        max_guesses-=1
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Python 3.x you can use `f strings` instead of `.format()`. In my opinion, it's a lot more practical.

```
num = 16
guess = 0
guess_limit = 3
while guess_limit > 0:

    guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1-99:"))

    if guess == num:
        guess_limit -= 1
        print(f"you guessed the number correctly you have {guess_limit} guesses remaining")
        break

    elif guess >= num:
        guess_limit-=1
        print(f"You guessed too high you have {guess_limit} guesses remaining")

    elif guess <= num:
        guess_limit-=1
        print(f"you guessed too low you have {guess_limit} guesses remmaining")

    if guess_limit == 0:
        print(
            f"Sorry you have run out of guesses  you have 0 guesses remaining"
            )   
        print("the number was", num)
```

Here's the code I did.

Comment: In the future you might want to note all of the changes you made. You didn't mention changing the final `elif` statement to `if`, but that's a pretty big part of your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I'll be sure to include my changes next time

Answer (score 1):

There are two notable problems:

You're decrementing `max_guesses`, starting at 0 and subtracting one with each guess. Your program checks to see if `max_guesses` equals `guess_limit`, but since `guess_limit` starts at 3, and `max_guesses` starts at 0 and always decrements, they'll never be equal.

The second problem is that the line where you check if they've run out of guesses, `elif max_guesses==guess_limit:`, is an `elif` block. Your program will never reach that block, since the three previous blocks cover every possible condition: the guessed number is equal, higher, and lower than the number they're trying to guess. You should include that block in a separate `if` statement.

Some other things I noticed (unrelated to the problem in your question):

- `elif guess >= num:` uses `>=` ("greater than or equal to"). You don't want this block to run if the guessed number is equal to the correct number—it should only run if it's greater than it. So, you should probably use only `>` in this case. It's the same thing with `<=` later in the program.
- You change `max_guesses` after you print out how many guesses they've used. It would make more sense to update it before you print it out.
- You use `max_guesses+2` to figure out how many guesses they have remaining. If their maximum number of allowed guesses is 3, wouldn't it make more sense to subtract the number of guesses they've taken from the maximum allowed, e.g. `guess_limit - max_guesses`?

Here it is with all of my suggestions:

```
num=16
guess=0
guess_limit=3
max_guesses=0

while max_guesses<guess_limit:
    guess=int(input("Enter a number between 1-99:"))
    if guess==num:
        max_guesses+=1
        print("you guessed the number correctly you have {} guesses remaining".format(guess_limit - max_guesses))
        break
    elif guess>=num:
        max_guesses+=1
        print("You guessed to high you have {} guesses remaining".format(guess_limit - max_guesses))
    elif guess<=num:
        max_guesses+=1
        print("you guessed to low you have {} guesses remmaining".format(guess_limit - max_guesses))
    
    if max_guesses==guess_limit:
        max_guesses+=1
        print("Sorry you have run out of guesses you have {} guesses remaining".format(guess_limit - max_guesses))
        print("the number was",num)
```